error 'Loop is not closed' in mongoDB Geospatial Query $geoWithin
currently using Geospatial Query of mongodb to search for point within polygon.
geojson is like :
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                103.959259,
                30.320742
              ],
              [
                103.93563,
                30.346203
              ],
              [
                103.942237,
                30.357773
              ],
              [
                103.913904,
                30.353972
              ],
              [
                103.910432,
                30.330663
              ],
              [
                103.887699,
                30.328761
              ],
              [
                103.87426,
                30.348104
              ],
              [
                103.845368,
                30.34331
              ],
              [
                103.794749,
                30.345872
              ],
              [
                103.769776,
                30.332068
              ],
              [
                103.75141,
                30.307927
              ],
              [
                103.727893,
                30.30462
              ],
              [
                103.736516,
                30.285848
              ],
              [
                103.718374,
                30.283201
              ],
              [
                103.705271,
                30.268975
              ],
              [
                103.681754,
                30.269885
              ],
              [
                103.693065,
                30.245894
              ],
              [
                103.648046,
                30.229263
              ],
              [
                103.649502,
                30.199799
              ],
              [
                103.628,
                30.214863
              ],
              [
                103.617473,
                30.195412
              ],
              [
                103.597204,
                30.203524
              ],
              [
                103.533819,
                30.178109
              ],
              [
                103.544233,
                30.161218
              ],
              [
                103.533819,
                30.146643
              ],
              [
                103.504142,
                30.128503
              ],
              [
                103.486224,
                30.104147
              ],
              [
                103.474577,
                30.131237
              ],
              [
                103.450948,
                30.132231
              ],
              [
                103.468082,
                30.114255
              ],
              [
                103.462483,
                30.096027
              ],
              [
                103.4505,
                30.096524
              ],
              [
                103.443893,
                30.117486
              ],
              [
                103.443893,
                30.120054
              ],
              [
                103.439637,
                30.119557
              ],
              [
                103.439637,
                30.119474
              ],
              [
                103.395178,
                30.094866
              ],
              [
                103.360574,
                30.136787
              ],
              [
                103.372109,
                30.148382
              ],
              [
                103.36091,
                30.168008
              ],
              [
                103.370317,
                30.22827
              ],
              [
                103.350047,
                30.236048
              ],
              [
                103.320259,
                30.23489
              ],
              [
                103.313875,
                30.260372
              ],
              [
                103.282295,
                30.263598
              ],
              [
                103.242651,
                30.243081
              ],
              [
                103.233356,
                30.213456
              ],
              [
                103.215998,
                30.209235
              ],
              [
                103.211631,
                30.232407
              ],
              [
                103.183634,
                30.248128
              ],
              [
                103.147238,
                30.207
              ],
              [
                103.076798,
                30.220242
              ],
              [
                103.071534,
                30.260951
              ],
              [
                103.061456,
                30.270464
              ],
              [
                103.068623,
                30.294283
              ],
              [
                103.062128,
                30.302553
              ],
              [
                103.079038,
                30.324545
              ],
              [
                103.091132,
                30.326529
              ],
              [
                103.127976,
                30.367111
              ],
              [
                103.116329,
                30.380002
              ],
              [
                103.115993,
                30.413954
              ],
              [
                103.12596,
                30.451115
              ],
              [
                103.141751,
                30.470845
              ],
              [
                103.162244,
                30.472579
              ],
              [
                103.185874,
                30.511945
              ],
              [
                103.180834,
                30.525228
              ],
              [
                103.157765,
                30.530013
              ],
              [
                103.166276,
                30.555749
              ],
              [
                103.147798,
                30.585847
              ],
              [
                103.126856,
                30.593927
              ],
              [
                103.135591,
                30.624096
              ],
              [
                103.13156,
                30.65475
              ],
              [
                103.119017,
                30.670898
              ],
              [
                103.103115,
                30.672957
              ],
              [
                103.068735,
                30.716194
              ],
              [
                103.031331,
                30.703678
              ],
              [
                103.033907,
                30.719076
              ],
              [
                103.005126,
                30.74649
              ],
              [
                102.992919,
                30.778339
              ],
              [
                103.037938,
                30.802364
              ],
              [
                103.083629,
                30.812728
              ],
              [
                103.123945,
                30.79282
              ],
              [
                103.165716,
                30.842171
              ],
              [
                103.199088,
                30.845707
              ],
              [
                103.228653,
                30.836579
              ],
              [
                103.25833,
                30.842418
              ],
              [
                103.284647,
                30.829589
              ],
              [
                103.305252,
                30.810507
              ],
              [
                103.337617,
                30.824655
              ],
              [
                103.354527,
                30.850887
              ],
              [
                103.383084,
                30.862891
              ],
              [
                103.409401,
                30.864946
              ],
              [
                103.451396,
                30.892565
              ],
              [
                103.454644,
                30.924695
              ],
              [
                103.465058,
                30.941536
              ],
              [
                103.516461,
                30.971761
              ],
              [
                103.52094,
                31.005095
              ],
              [
                103.517132,
                31.030129
              ],
              [
                103.504814,
                31.041044
              ],
              [
                103.521164,
                31.067792
              ],
              [
                103.525644,
                31.101092
              ],
              [
                103.557224,
                31.149055
              ],
              [
                103.564839,
                31.175034
              ],
              [
                103.583205,
                31.191422
              ],
              [
                103.57671,
                31.215834
              ],
              [
                103.581413,
                31.246626
              ],
              [
                103.569095,
                31.262019
              ],
              [
                103.579733,
                31.291241
              ],
              [
                103.569991,
                31.314563
              ],
              [
                103.569543,
                31.338453
              ],
              [
                103.60717,
                31.351295
              ],
              [
                103.627104,
                31.344097
              ],
              [
                103.669323,
                31.354812
              ],
              [
                103.700792,
                31.391118
              ],
              [
                103.739876,
                31.398885
              ],
              [
                103.75029,
                31.419156
              ],
              [
                103.787246,
                31.434439
              ],
              [
                103.802588,
                31.430108
              ],
              [
                103.816027,
                31.431906
              ],
              [
                103.828682,
                31.412454
              ],
              [
                103.868437,
                31.420954
              ],
              [
                103.897554,
                31.416377
              ],
              [
                103.894754,
                31.408858
              ],
              [
                103.92835,
                31.355139
              ],
              [
                103.894418,
                31.326018
              ],
              [
                103.891618,
                31.308017
              ],
              [
                103.914128,
                31.278964
              ],
              [
                103.928014,
                31.272497
              ],
              [
                103.929134,
                31.234425
              ],
              [
                103.949404,
                31.215997
              ],
              [
                103.983,
                31.200925
              ],
              [
                104.014693,
                31.167577
              ],
              [
                104.009429,
                31.153235
              ],
              [
                104.022868,
                31.142661
              ],
              [
                104.019844,
                31.103963
              ],
              [
                104.057584,
                31.07821
              ],
              [
                104.060608,
                31.0641
              ],
              [
                104.094876,
                31.032756
              ],
              [
                104.10641,
                31.031771
              ],
              [
                104.106522,
                31.031607
              ],
              [
                104.107194,
                31.032017
              ],
              [
                104.10697,
                31.032263
              ],
              [
                104.117385,
                31.017572
              ],
              [
                104.143478,
                31.01158
              ],
              [
                104.166884,
                30.993438
              ],
              [
                104.166324,
                30.951311
              ],
              [
                104.142582,
                30.925845
              ],
              [
                104.149974,
                30.91311
              ],
              [
                104.168787,
                30.918533
              ],
              [
                104.202384,
                30.91311
              ],
              [
                104.21571,
                30.8984
              ],
              [
                104.244491,
                30.896921
              ],
              [
                104.288726,
                30.90292
              ],
              [
                104.322322,
                30.891743
              ],
              [
                104.351887,
                30.902345
              ],
              [
                104.367117,
                30.93365
              ],
              [
                104.389739,
                30.925681
              ],
              [
                104.39601,
                30.942358
              ],
              [
                104.44506,
                30.940468
              ],
              [
                104.465218,
                30.9509
              ],
              [
                104.495791,
                30.935457
              ],
              [
                104.511917,
                30.935868
              ],
              [
                104.533083,
                30.917875
              ],
              [
                104.520764,
                30.882456
              ],
              [
                104.585269,
                30.862891
              ],
              [
                104.596355,
                30.864535
              ],
              [
                104.613937,
                30.847763
              ],
              [
                104.629952,
                30.852449
              ],
              [
                104.640366,
                30.837895
              ],
              [
                104.698376,
                30.825559
              ],
              [
                104.718086,
                30.771756
              ],
              [
                104.732084,
                30.778257
              ],
              [
                104.750786,
                30.726898
              ],
              [
                104.768032,
                30.71817
              ],
              [
                104.788526,
                30.721299
              ],
              [
                104.78875,
                30.694043
              ],
              [
                104.800956,
                30.690995
              ],
              [
                104.818315,
                30.664307
              ],
              [
                104.821226,
                30.643874
              ],
              [
                104.842728,
                30.649395
              ],
              [
                104.847319,
                30.631101
              ],
              [
                104.819994,
                30.598296
              ],
              [
                104.819098,
                30.580076
              ],
              [
                104.858854,
                30.582385
              ],
              [
                104.879124,
                30.550635
              ],
              [
                104.892786,
                30.541645
              ],
              [
                104.8761,
                30.5131
              ],
              [
                104.875092,
                30.437078
              ],
              [
                104.881699,
                30.393551
              ],
              [
                104.895922,
                30.382315
              ],
              [
                104.881027,
                30.360831
              ],
              [
                104.860982,
                30.364384
              ],
              [
                104.855494,
                30.347194
              ],
              [
                104.837016,
                30.361988
              ],
              [
                104.850455,
                30.338929
              ],
              [
                104.848775,
                30.306852
              ],
              [
                104.823354,
                30.293787
              ],
              [
                104.807228,
                30.296847
              ],
              [
                104.795133,
                30.279397
              ],
              [
                104.774863,
                30.30156
              ],
              [
                104.738579,
                30.290314
              ],
              [
                104.723797,
                30.308341
              ],
              [
                104.703975,
                30.301643
              ],
              [
                104.691993,
                30.275427
              ],
              [
                104.643614,
                30.283036
              ],
              [
                104.638239,
                30.268148
              ],
              [
                104.653133,
                30.240185
              ],
              [
                104.599603,
                30.244488
              ],
              [
                104.600163,
                30.220408
              ],
              [
                104.569254,
                30.196985
              ],
              [
                104.541594,
                30.184236
              ],
              [
                104.533754,
                30.193673
              ],
              [
                104.484368,
                30.181504
              ],
              [
                104.485264,
                30.156001
              ],
              [
                104.468354,
                30.157077
              ],
              [
                104.464994,
                30.151529
              ],
              [
                104.449428,
                30.132894
              ],
              [
                104.457715,
                30.120634
              ],
              [
                104.437109,
                30.107544
              ],
              [
                104.450212,
                30.101081
              ],
              [
                104.428374,
                30.089729
              ],
              [
                104.41012,
                30.125521
              ],
              [
                104.39881,
                30.124776
              ],
              [
                104.386379,
                30.161798
              ],
              [
                104.358158,
                30.173638
              ],
              [
                104.364541,
                30.185974
              ],
              [
                104.327138,
                30.204269
              ],
              [
                104.315379,
                30.200792
              ],
              [
                104.282231,
                30.220904
              ],
              [
                104.2726,
                30.217842
              ],
              [
                104.264537,
                30.241592
              ],
              [
                104.243259,
                30.244239
              ],
              [
                104.23094,
                30.256153
              ],
              [
                104.243371,
                30.267403
              ],
              [
                104.231836,
                30.280472
              ],
              [
                104.23318,
                30.281051
              ],
              [
                104.232732,
                30.281878
              ],
              [
                104.2315,
                30.282209
              ],
              [
                104.232284,
                30.313798
              ],
              [
                104.2016,
                30.316526
              ],
              [
                104.192977,
                30.329836
              ],
              [
                104.17853,
                30.318262
              ],
              [
                104.174051,
                30.298666
              ],
              [
                104.152213,
                30.265335
              ],
              [
                104.150533,
                30.245646
              ],
              [
                104.116601,
                30.227194
              ],
              [
                104.091628,
                30.24879
              ],
              [
                104.047393,
                30.270381
              ],
              [
                104.030035,
                30.266245
              ],
              [
                104.030035,
                30.266245
              ],
              [
                103.998343,
                30.264508
              ],
              [
                103.974713,
                30.290727
              ],
              [
                103.965866,
                30.316774
              ],
              [
                103.959259,
                30.320742
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

this could be viewed in https://geojson.io.

db.location.find({
  lnglat:{
    $geoWithin : {
      $geometry : {
        type:"Polygon",
        coordinates:[
            [
                [ 103.959259, 30.320742 ] , // start loop
                 ......
                [ 103.959259, 30.320742 ] // close loop
            ]   
        ]
       }
     } 
   }
}) 

as start coordinate and close coordinates are the same value.
but still got mongodb error saying:
MongoServerError: Loop is not valid

Edges 139 and 141 cross. Edge locations in degrees: [31.0316070, 104.1065220]-[31.0320170, 104.1071940] and [31.0322630, 104.1069700]-[31.0175720, 104.1173850]

it seems something wrong with geojson , but don't know how to fix it ?

Add a feature to your geojson.io {"type": "Feature","properties": {},"geometry": {"coordinates": [104.10664384169854,31.032212771774695],"type": "Point"}}, then zoom in on that point to see the problem.

Looking at the positions in the error message you have two paths crossing which you can't have with a polygon. If that type of shape is intentional (might be as you haven't shared the full cords of the query) then you can try with $geoWithin : { $geometry : { type: "MultiPolygon", rather than type:"Polygon". See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225368/understanding-difference-between-polygon-and-multipolygon-for-shapefiles-in-qgis for difference between polygon and MultiPolygon.

I suggest to check your polygon with JTS Topology Suite, it's a single Java File you have to download and run:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx1024M
java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar JTSTestBuilder.jar

When you put your polygon into the tool and check it, then you get this picture:

When you zoom in, then you see the problem:

I would suggest simply to delete this single coordinate causing the intersection.
